# Can I run 12.04 on this netbook?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, ubuntu-netbook

So, my laptop died. I have an old netbook. It has Ubuntu 10.04, and the upgrade manager says I can install 12.04. My question is, will this netbook run smoothly with it? Also, will it support newer versions?

The netbook is a Point of View Mobii 9040, with these specs:

- Processor:Intel Atom N450 1.66 GHz
- Chipset:Intel NM10 Express Chipset
- Graphics chipset:Intel GMA 3150
- Storage:250GB SATA
- RAM:1GB DDR2 SDRAM
- LAN:RJ45 10/100Mbps

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably [Lubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://lubuntu.net) is a better choice for it.

I recommend you to make a bootable USB-Flash with Lubuntu on it, and try it first without installation. If it will run correctly, then you can perform the installation from it.

Answer (score 0):

It will run and everything will work. However Unity has some effects that drag down even my new up to date desktop, so I can't imagine what it would do to your laptop.  If it is a matter of performance I would recommend Lubuntu or even better Puppy Linux, which is specially built to be an OS meant for lower end/old computers.  I think you would find the transition very easy and worthwhile.  You might consider doing a live USB/CD before committing. Take them both for a test drive and see what you think.

[Here](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) is puppy linux :)

Good Luck!